# Where does the Muffin Man live in Shrek?

Tags: shrek

Yes, I know he lives on Drury Lane, but where is Drury Lane located? I thought it was in Far Far Away, but the Shrek Wiki says Duloc, since Lord Farquaad knew about him. I changed Duloc to Far Far Away on the Muffin Man's Shrek Wiki page, but it got changed back to Duloc? So which kingdom does he live in?

Comment: Just a note, unless you have a source, I would recommend not editing wikis. Adding information just because one “thought” that’s what it was is what makes wikis so low quality.

Comment: There could be two muffin men and also, Gingy is clearly lying to Farquaad.

Comment: @NKCampbell I'm confident there's up to 13 Muffin Men.

Comment: @NKCampbell Excuse me, he did what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Gingerbread Man apparently lives Duloc during the original *Shrek*, being close enough for Lord Farquaad to torture in the first movie.  He mentions the Muffin Man, but we do not see the Muffin Man in that movie, or have any indication of where he lives (aside from "Drury Lane").  Watching only *Shrek*, we might reasonably conclude the Muffin Man lives in Duloc - why else would Gingerbread Man and Lord Farquaad discuss Drury Lane so casually?

However, in *Shrek 2*, we see the Gingerbread Man reunited with the Muffin Man, and they conspire to create Mongo and storm the castle in Far Far Away.  Given the distance between Duloc and Far Far Away ("pok!") it seems clear that the Muffin Man lives in Far Far Away.

I would say that, having watched only *Shrek*, it would be reasonable to *assume* that the Muffin Man, and Drury Lane, were in Duloc.  But to move *Shrek 2* along, the Muffin Man was concretely placed in Far Far Away.

So the answer is different depending on which movie you want to reference.

Comment: Perhaps the Muffin Man relocated to Far Far Away during Farquaad's persecution of fairy tale creatures. The interrogation scene seems to imply that the Muffin Man and/or his wife had been granting asylum to wanted fairy tail creatures; it makes sense that they'd want to flee for the safety of both their fugitive friends and themselves.

Comment: maybe the Muffin Man moved to FFA between the events of Shrek and Shrek 2?

Comment: nice! @DaniellYancey - great minds thinking alike

Comment: I think "moved" is an excellent theory, guys, but between "well-crafted explanation" and "sloppy continuity" the *Shrek* movies only get one vote from me...

Comment: Another Shrek Wiki user changed it back to Far Far Away, so no need to worry about it anymore.